# Looping and writing into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, assign

I am writing a program that will be able to manipulate data about precipitation from various years to print out mean annual rainfall, monthly average etc. I have a `int[] getYears()` method in my class which is supposed to extract all the available years and return these as an integer array.

Here is my compiled code, but I am not sure whether what I am doing is actually correct:

```
public class Rainfall {

private RainfallYear[] rainfallYears = null;
private int[] getYears = null;

public int[] getYears() {

    for (RainfallYear rainfallYearObject : rainfallYears) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
            getYears[i] = rainfallYearObject.getYear();
        }
    }

    return getYears;
}

public Rainfall(RainfallYear[] rainfallYears) {
    super();
    this.rainfallYears = rainfallYears;
} 
}
```

Here are the steps to my thinking:

1. Years are stored in the rainfallYearObject, which is within the rainfallYears array.
2. Depending on the amount of years given, I want to get every year and put it into the getYears array.

What is bothering me is this line

```
getYears[i] = rainfallYearObject.getYear();
```

I have a feeling that this is logically wrong, even though I do not get any errors. Am I on the right track, or completely off?

UML Diagram:

[image: Project UML]

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include a tag of the language you are programming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple areas for improvement here, assuming what you posted is your entire class:

1.) You don't need to assign null to your fields (rainfallYears and getYears) when you first declare them. You don't need to assign anything to them when you first declare them.

2.) Change the name of either your getYears field, or your getYears method. It could get confusing having a field and a method with the same name.

3.) You need to either set the size of your arrays, or use something with a mutable size, like ArrayLists <-- *This will help address the part that you said is bothering you*

4.) In your for loops, you have a for-each loop ("for each rainfallYear in rainfallYears") and a for loop (counting by an index, i in your case). Pick one or the other, but you don't need both. If you stick with using Arrays, use a for loop (the indexed kind)

5.) In your constructor, set your getYears field equal to the result of your getYears method (but again, rename one of them).

6.) Given that both of your fields are private, you will probably want to have public getter methods to make the values accessible outside of the class (if you do intact want them to be accessible).

Hope this helps :)